# How to add an extra speaker to my existing audio system?

Tags: windows-10, audio, bluetooth, speakers, surround-sound

I have **windows 10** running on my laptop. I have connected **stereo speakers** to it via the existing **3.5 mm audio jack**.

I want to connect *one* *more* *speaker* via *Bluetooth* and want to play the *same content* on *all* of the speakers *simultaneously* or if that is impossible I would be equally satisfied even if I am able to play some *different* content in the *Bluetooth speakers* via my laptop and *different* content on *stereo speakers simultaneously*.

Now how do I do this? Without extra hardware.

Highly appreciate your help!

Comment: Without buying said speakers it's going to be difficult. You would do this by having a sound card (driver) that supports it and configuring your application(s) accordingly. Some will switch the output device when you switch your default device and some won't. You could use something like a virtual sound card to create channel which is used by the application and let both speakers listen to it. What have you actually tried so far?

Comment: I have bought the speakers.(simple desktop speakers and a Bluetooth speaker). That virtual sound card idea sounds good. I've not tried much with third party apps so far.

Comment: I would be grateful if you could suggest me an appropriate software for this. Thanks in advance.